# How to access multiple div elements (block level elements) from javascript, to change the transform property of all elememts?

Tags: javascript, css

According to this snippet, I want all the boxes to rotate 180deg. I can do it by applying different ID names. But what I want is, without applying different Id's I want to rotate the boxes on one single  click:

```js
function home() {
  var change = document.getElementById("boxes");
  change.style.background = "rgba(55, 111, 172, 0.408)";
  change.style.webkitTransform = "rotateZ(180deg)";
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

.box1 {
  background: rgba(111, 154, 201, 0.808);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.box2 {
  background: rgba(90, 134, 180, 0.808);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="boxes" class="box1"></div>
  <div id="boxes" class="box2"></div>
  <div id="boxes" class="box1"></div>
  <div id="boxes" class="box2"></div>
  <div id="boxes" class="box1"></div>
  <div id="boxes" class="box2"></div>
  <div id="boxes" class="box1"></div>
  <div id="boxes" class="box2"></div>
</div>
<button id="btn" onclick="home()">submit</button>
```

Comment: ID should be *unique*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give "boxes" class to all your boxes. Then you can use this to query all elements

```
var elementsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("boxes");
```

Then use a for loop to change their style.

```
for (var i = 0; elementsArray.length; i++) {
   elementsArray[i].style.background = "rgba(55, 111, 172, 0.408)";
   elementsArray[i].style.webkitTransform = "rotateZ(180deg)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ids` are unique, you cannot have more than 2 elements with same `id`. Instead you can get all the `div`s inside `.wrap` class using `querySelectorAll` or selecting the `div` with there class names.

```js
function home() {
  // document.querySelectorAll(".box2, .box1") -> with same class name
  document.querySelectorAll(".wrap > div")
    .forEach(box => {
      box.style.background = "rgba(55, 111, 172, 0.408)";
      box.style.webkitTransform = "rotateZ(180deg)";
    });
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

.box1 {
  background: rgba(111, 154, 201, 0.808);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.box2 {
  background: rgba(90, 134, 180, 0.808);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
</div>
<button id="btn" onclick="home()">submit</button>
```

-- Edit --

In order to have the `boxes` background color as initial, once the animation is completed, add `transitionend` event, which get fired once the transition is complete and change the background color back to the original color.

```js
document.querySelector('#btn')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".wrap > div")
      .forEach(box => {
        box.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
          this.style.background = this.classList.contains('box1') ? "rgba(111, 154, 201, 0.808)" : "rgba(90, 134, 180, 0.808)";
        });

        box.style.background = "rgba(55, 111, 172, 0.408)";
        box.style.transform = "rotateZ(180deg)";
      });
  });
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

.box1 {
  background: rgba(111, 154, 201, 0.808);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.box2 {
  background: rgba(90, 134, 180, 0.808);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
</div>
<button id="btn">submit</button>
```

Comment: what if i want to 2 different colors for boxes (one color for box1 and other for box2)?

Comment: @mohamedfaizankhan - box1 and box2 already have two different background colors. please clarify more.

Comment: when i hit submit button the color is changing to rgba(55, 111, 172, 0.408)..but what i want is, when i hit submit button.. box1 should have a different color and box2 should have a different color.

Comment: check this repo(https://github.com/FaizanKhan7/background.git) i want this to be responsive to all the devices starting from 320px 1200px..

Comment: I would be more than happy to help you, but "i want this responsive", is like you are asking me to write code for you and this site is not for that. You have to try and in case if face any kind of problem then people are here to help you. Also,  you have to make separate question for this.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for your help.